# Can we set the order or any type of priority while running android test cases?

Tags: android, testing, android-testing

Suppose there is an android specific test cases is given as follows, as android instrumentation test cases running order is always not the same,

```
public class MainActivityUnitTest extends
    android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase<MainActivity> {

  private int buttonId;
  private MainActivity activity;

  public MainActivityUnitTest() {
    super(MainActivity.class);
  }
  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
        MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent, null, null);
    activity = getActivity();
  }

  public void testLayout() {
    buttonId = com.vogella.android.test.simpleactivity.R.id.button1;
    assertNotNull(activity.findViewById(buttonId));
    Button view = (Button) activity.findViewById(buttonId);
    assertEquals("Incorrect label of the button", "Start", view.getText());
  }
  public void testLayoutFirst() {//some test cases specific code here ....}
  public void testLayoutSecond() {//some test cases specific code} here...}

  public void testIntentTriggerViaOnClick() {
    buttonId = com.vogella.android.test.simpleactivity.R.id.button1;
    Button view = (Button) activity.findViewById(buttonId);
    assertNotNull("Button not allowed to be null", view);

    view.performClick();

    // TouchUtils cannot be used, only allowed in 
    // InstrumentationTestCase or ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 

    // Check the intent which was started
    Intent triggeredIntent = getStartedActivityIntent();
    assertNotNull("Intent was null", triggeredIntent);
    String data = triggeredIntent.getExtras().getString("URL");

    assertEquals("Incorrect data passed via the intent",
        "http://www.vogella.com", data);
  }

}
```

**Question :** My question is , is there any way that we can set the order of android instrumentation test cases while they are running as i always seen that the running order of android test cases may same or different every time, so can we set any type of priority or order of there running sequence?.

In the above given test case code there are more than one test cases and each time the running sequence may differ than the previous one , so can we have a fixed order of there running sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Use the annotation below,

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
```